# Get best 3 scores in Optaplanner?

Tags: drools, optaplanner

Can we get top 3 best scores using constraints in Optaplanner?

For eg i have a use case where i need to show top 3 results which has highest score to user so that user can select the solution according to their need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like **pareto** optimization (see docs). Not yet supported in OptaPlanner officially.

But users have hacked it before, by implementing their own `BestSolutionRecaller` (= that class that holds the best solution(s)) and replacing the `DefaultSolver`'s `bestSolutionRecaller` with it. This implies "taking the red pill" and "following the rabbit hole down to wonderland". Good luck :)

Important note: Pareto optimization goes much further than just remember the n best solutions. It's about remember the n best solutions which aren't dominated by one of the other best solutions. So it entails changing the score comparison (and breaking the transitive aspect of score comparison).

Comment: Any chance in future to support this pareto optimization? When can we expect this to be officially launched?

Comment: It won't be in 6.2 (unless someone comes up with a really nice Pull Request of course). I haven't finalized what's in 6.3 yet, but I'd like to add concurrent solving for 6.3, in which case they won't be any bandwidth for pareto either. So it won't be officially supported any time soon :(

Comment: Could you provide this code for basesolutionrecaller,as i really need this feature of having top best solutions?

Comment: No, sorry. That would take hours, so that way beyond answering a free community support question.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet: If we have a SimpleScore and we know that there will be several optimal solutions with the same value isn't there a simpler way than full-blown Pareto? I assume we'd need to only override BestSolutionRecaller, and not (as mentioned for Pareto scoring in the docs) ScoreDefinition or Score. (Only one mention of BestSolutionRecaller in the docs, so not sure how involved that is.)

Comment: @Wayne yes, and users have done it before. There is indeed something between getBestSolution() and getAllParetoBestSolutions(), namely getBestSolutions(). That hasn't been implemented yet, but will be implemented together with parato someday. Meanwhile the BestSolutionRecaller hack should work. Do set a hard limit on the number of solutions to retain. There can easily be trillions with the same score that are 90% equal.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet: Thanks! I'm thinking three solutions, like the OP. Basically just to give the human planner options so they can have one last choice that can accommodate the "just don't like the looks of that", one-off/hazy constraints. In my case, I know that they will be equal score-wise, not just "the top three".