# OptaPlanner - Get n best solutions with equal score

Tags: optaplanner

We have a use-case where we need to return the "top-N-best-solutions" for a problem using OptaPlanner. Unlike pareto we are going to compare scores of similar entities. Going through the OptaPlanner docs and other questions here I see that there have been multiple mentions of a "hack" involving *BestSolutionRecaller* to achieve this behavior in the cases where the "bestSolutionChanged" listener will not be triggered for solutions with equal best scores.

So since it is still not officially supported yet, in the meantime wanted to know if the "hack" is still doable or has that been closed as well ? Is there any other way (a better one) by which we can achieve this result until it is officially supported  by OptaPlanner (as part of Pareto scoring or other feature) ?

P.S.: Not sure if the approach involving BestSolutionRecaller is still valid as it was earlier mentioned in the official docs under pareto score support but seems to have been removed lately.

The use case/expectation is exactly similar to this existing question -
[Get best 3 scores in Optaplanner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441711/get-best-3-scores-in-optaplanner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the question and answer you point to is still the status quo.

Comment: Oh okay.. I am still exploring how to override the DefaultSolver with custom BestSolutionRecaller so wanted to know if it is possible to get it working with SolverManager or can be only done while creating it with SolverFactory.. Also, any pointers around how to inject a custom solver if possible would be great. Thanks.

Comment: No, this will not be possible with `SolverManager`. That API hides the solver pretty thoroughly.